# Getting an angle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I have a unit circle, and two angles: $\alpha=\angle{JON}\in[0,\pi]$ and $\beta=\angle{IOM}\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Using angles, we can get points $N$, $M$ as on the image. Then, dropping a perpendicular from point $N$ to line $OM$ we can get point $A$.

Now, let us have another angle $\gamma=\angle{IOB}$.

The problem is how to calculate an angle $x=\angle{MAB}$ as a function of $\gamma$.

[image]

**EDIT:**

The original problem is mapping real rime cycle to astronomic time.
Let the circle around $IOJ$ be the system of time representation. Time goes anticlockwise. Point $I=0$ (right) is 06:00, $J=0.5\cdot\pi$ (top) is 12:00, $-0.5\cdot\pi$ (bottom) is 00:00, $\pi$ is 18:00.

The [sunrise equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation) gives us a sun noon, sunrise and sunset time for a current location. Let $M$ point be the noon time. We can set also $N$ point as sunrise time. Now, we can build a coordinate system in which $0$ will be real sunrise, $0.5\cdot\pi$ - real astronomic noon, etc.

Values $\in [0,\pi]$ will be the daytime, $[-\pi,0]$, resp. the nighttime.

I like MvG's idea of solution, but it seems to be unrealistic on the graphic: cardinality of the set of positive and negative values are the same, but should be different for chosen parameters $\alpha, \beta$.

As an illustration, cycle obtained using formula $\tan x = \frac{\sin(\gamma-\beta)}{\cos(\gamma-\beta)-\sin(\alpha+\beta)}$. Red line is original time cycle, cyan one is transformed cycle:

[image]

**EDIT2:**

After a little playing with coeffitients I have got such graphic:

[image]

The top picture represents a long day (summer), the bottom is a winter. I think, this solution looks adequately. Thanks @MvG.

Comment: Do you know how to compute coordinates for points, $A$ in particular? Do you know how to use trigonometric functions to compute angles from coordinates? Have you tried considering the simpler case where $A$ is an arbitrary point on the segment $OI$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define coordinates as follows:

\begin{align*}
O &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix} &
N &= \begin{pmatrix}\sin\alpha\\\cos\alpha\end{pmatrix} &
M &= \begin{pmatrix}\cos\beta\\\sin\beta\end{pmatrix} &
B &= \begin{pmatrix}\cos\gamma\\\sin\gamma\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

With a bit of computation (I did this using projective geometry, i.e. using homgenous coordinates and cross products), you can from this determine

$$
A = \sin(\alpha+\beta)\cdot M =
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin(\alpha + \beta)\,\cos(\beta) \\
\sin(\alpha + \beta)\,\sin(\beta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then you can compute the direction vector of the line $AB$:

$$
B-A=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\gamma - \sin(\alpha+\beta)\,\cos\beta \\
\sin\gamma - \sin(\alpha+\beta)\,\sin\beta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

One could turn that direction vector into a slope, but you don't want the angle with the horizontal axis, but instead the angle with the line $OM$. Therefore you rotate the vector above by an angle of $\beta$ clockwise. This will take the line $OM$ to the horizontal axis.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\beta & \sin\beta \\
-\sin\beta & \cos\beta
\end{pmatrix}\cdot(B-A) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\gamma-\beta)-\sin(\alpha+\beta) \\
\sin(\gamma-\beta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

From this you can conclude

$$\tan x = \frac{\sin(\gamma-\beta)}{\cos(\gamma-\beta)-\sin(\alpha+\beta)}$$

To solve this for $x$ you'd best use a function like `atan2` which can keep track of the appropriate quadrant. If you don't agree with the sign of this solution, feel free to flip it.

As an illustration, here is $x(\gamma)$ for $\alpha=60°,\beta=40°$:
[image: Example plot: alpha=60°, beta=40°]

Comment: Thanks @MvG. Good solution, but seems a bit inaccurate yet. See my question fix please.

Comment: @AlexanderMihailov: Not sure I understand all the details of your post correctly, but from your picture it seems to me that you measure $x$ from the noon position $M$, not from the sunrise position $N$. So $-\frac\pi2\le x\le\frac\pi2$ would be day and $\frac\pi2\le\lvert x\rvert\le\pi$ would be night. In my example graph it would be deep winter with very short days, while your graph would represent summer.

Comment: Got it, thank you. There were some inaccuracies with initial formulation of problem. In particular, I wanted to find $NOB$ instead of $MOB$. Also it's better to use $\alpha=ION$ instead of $JON$. After transformations, finite formula is: $$\tan x = \frac{\sin(\gamma-\beta)}{\cos(\gamma-\beta) - \cos(\alpha-\beta)}$$